# Any set path returns me to the main Page

Tags: go, web

So I have this code:

```golang
func main() {
    Users, err := Profiles.Read("./dat/users.json")
    HandleError(err)
    http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("views/static"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/", Route.ROUTE_MAIN(Users))
    http.HandleFunc("/login", Route.ROUTE_LOGIN(Users))
    http.HandleFunc("/logout", Route.ROUTE_LOGOUT(Users))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

```golang
func ROUTE_MAIN(Users *Profiles.ProfileList) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        AuthDat := Users.Authenticate(w, r)
        if AuthDat.Is {
            if err := TEMPLATE_MAIN.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", nil); err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }

            return
        } else {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusPermanentRedirect)
        }
    }
}

func ROUTE_LOGOUT(Users *Profiles.ProfileList) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        AuthDat := Users.Authenticate(w, r)
        if AuthDat.Is {
            http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{Name: "auth", Value: "", Expires: time.Now()})
            if err := TEMPLATE_LOGOUT.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", map[string]string{"User": AuthDat.User.Username}); err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            }
        } else {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusPermanentRedirect)
        }
    }
}

func ROUTE_LOGIN(Users *Profiles.ProfileList) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        AuthDat := Users.Authenticate(w, r)
        if !AuthDat.Is {
            switch r.Method {
            case http.MethodPost:
                err := r.ParseForm()
                if err != nil {
                    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                }
                if username, ok := r.Form["username"]; ok {
                    if dec_password, ok := r.Form["password"]; ok {
                        usr, found := Users.GetUserByUsername(username[0])
                        if found {
                            if usr.Password == Profiles.Hash256(dec_password[0]) {
                                expiration := time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24)
                                if remember, ok := r.Form["remember"]; ok && remember[0] == "on" {
                                    expiration = time.Now().Add((time.Hour * 24) * 365)
                                }
                                http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{Name: "auth", Value: usr.Token, Expires: expiration})
                                http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusPermanentRedirect)

                            } else {
                                if err := TEMPLATE_LOGIN.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", map[string]string{
                                    "Error": "Incorrect Password",
                                }); err != nil {
                                    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if err := TEMPLATE_LOGIN.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", map[string]string{
                                "Error": "That user does not Exist.",
                            }); err != nil {
                                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if err := TEMPLATE_LOGIN.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", map[string]string{
                            "Error": "No Password Recieved.",
                        }); err != nil {
                            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if err := TEMPLATE_LOGIN.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", map[string]string{
                        "Error": "No Username Recieved.",
                    }); err != nil {
                        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    }
                }
                return
            case http.MethodGet:
                if err := TEMPLATE_LOGIN.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", nil); err != nil {
                    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    return
                }
            }
            return
        } else {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusPermanentRedirect)
        }
    }
}
```

`Route.ROUTE_MAIN` checks if there are any cookies, if so, make sure it belongs to an existing user and if so render the page, otherwise redirect to `/login`. Now, whenever I try to go to `/logout` It just sends me back to `/`. I tried adding this to `Route.ROUTE_MAIN`:

```golang
if(r.URL.Path != "/"){
    return
}
```

And It still moves me back to `/`.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: what's in ROUTE_LOGIN ?

Comment: Edit the question to show the code for the handler at /logout.

Comment: I've added all the routes